# Sony Xperia Z density seems odd to me, will my app work fine on it?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, sony

I'm developing an app for school project. My professor has Sony Xperia Z and will be testing my app on it, so I'm trying to make sure that my app will work most perfectly on Sony Xperia Z. I have set up a Sony Xperia Z AVD in Eclipse and the results are really odd to be honest.

This is how the app layout looks on most devices:
[image]

And this is how it looks like when I run it on Sony Xperia Z emulator:
[image]

I did some research and Sony Xperia Z really does have a lot smaller density than the other phones, but should everything really be this small? If this is really how the app will look like on Sony Xperia Z, how do I fix it? Is it simply going to get fixed by creating different density icons? But then how do I fix the text size? The text on Sony Xperia Z will be barely readable if it stays the same.

Comment: "how do I fix it?" -- that is impossible to answer in the abstract, as we have no idea what you are doing. In the future, consider providing more details of your code in your questions. "Is it simply going to get fixed by creating different density icons?" -- that depends on a variety of factors, such as how you are using the icons, what your resource directories are, etc. "But then how do I fix the text size?" -- specify your text size in units other than `px`, to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sony Xperia Z use xhpdi so put your resources in xhpdi and you can put your layout under screen size X-large. If you want to test your app in emulator you can use this http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

Comment: Hi Russ,I tried to Create Values-sw390dp folder(seperate UI) in for Sony Xperia Z in ANdroid Eclipse Project.but, when execute my project,It has taken the value from values-large only folder only.can u say how to put separate values folder for particular mobile Model in android.like Sony Xperia Z,Google Nexus7.. why because, both mobiles taking values from large only. thats why, i cant fit the UI for Both Models at one App..